# How should I use Firefox 'SQL Inject ME' addon with WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions?

Tags: asp.net, firefox-addon, sql-injection, form-submit

Dear Smart people out there,

I'm trying to use '**SQL inject me**' Firefox addon on a web page that Submits using WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions.

The tool produces results, but I see nothing happening in the SQL Profiler, 
as opposed to when I click the save button myself.

Should I trust the results? Can I force the addon to click the save button?

Thank you,
AllWorkNoPlay